# Bootstrap Tree View Does Not Work - passed Object still no output

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap

after reading ton of threads and solving one problem after one.
I stack at one big problem, there is no output.

As I mentioned I use Bootstrap Tree View:

In order to define the hierarchical structure needed for the tree it's necessary to provide a nested array of JavaScript objects.

Example

```
 var tree = [
      {
        text: "Parent 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Child 1",
            nodes: [
              {
                text: "Grandchild 1"
              },
              {
                text: "Grandchild 2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            text: "Child 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Parent 2"
      },
      {
        text: "Parent 3"
      },
      {
        text: "Parent 4"
      },
      {
        text: "Parent 5"
      }
    ];
```

My Category Array Output:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => Housing
            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/housing/housing
            [tags] => ['5']
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => House
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/house/house
                            [tags] => ['20']
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Shared Apartments - Rooms
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/shared-apartments-rooms/shared-apartments-rooms
                            [tags] => ['19']
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Apartment
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/apartment/apartment
                            [tags] => ['18']
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Jobs
            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/jobs/jobs
            [tags] => ['2']
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Full Time
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/full-time/full-time
                            [tags] => ['7']
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Part Time
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/part-time/part-time
                            [tags] => ['8']
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Internship
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/internship/internship
                            [tags] => ['9']
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Au pair
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/au-pair/au-pair
                            [tags] => ['10']
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => Languages
            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/languages/languages
            [tags] => ['3']
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => English
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/english/english
                            [tags] => ['11']
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Spanish
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/spanish/spanish
                            [tags] => ['12']
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Other Languages
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/other-languages/other-languages
                            [tags] => ['13']
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => Friendship
            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/friendship/friendship
            [tags] => ['17']
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => Market
            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/market/market
            [tags] => ['6']
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => TV
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/tv/tv
                            [tags] => ['21']
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Audio
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/audio/audio
                            [tags] => ['22']
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Furniture
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/furniture/furniture
                            [tags] => ['23']
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => IT
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/it/it
                            [tags] => ['24']
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Other Market
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/other-market/other-market
                            [tags] => ['25']
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => Others
            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/others/others
            [tags] => ['4']
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Events
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/events/events
                            [tags] => ['14']
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Hobbies
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/hobbies/hobbies
                            [tags] => ['15']
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Services
                            [href] => http://localhost/projekte/application/services/services
                            [tags] => ['16']
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is the code which should display the Tree:

```
 <div class="treeview" id="treeview1">
            <ul class="list-group">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var js_data = <?php json_encode($tree,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>;
            var js_obj_data = JSON.parse(js_data );
            function getTree() {
                return js_obj_data;
            }
            $('#treeview1').treeview({data: getTree()});
        </script>
```

NOTE: I read all the threads I found no answer to my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            var js_data = <?php echo json_encode($tree,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
           //  var js_obj_data = JSON.parse(js_data );
         //   alert(js_data.toSource);
        function getTree() {
            return js_data;
        }
        $('#treeview1').treeview({data: getTree()});
        });
    </script>
```